# Yii2 Вывести набор данных по набору id

Tags: php, mysql, массивы, yii2, gridview

проблема такая:

Есть 2 таблицы

таблица - company['id','name','contract_id']

таблица - contract['id', 'name']

К компаниям нужно привязать несколько договоров из таблицы contract

Это реализовано, договора привязываются, в базе это выглядит так:

в поле contract_id(varchar) в таблице company хранятся id'шники 13,28,43....

Вот как это реализовано:

**action в companyController**

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Company();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $model->contract_id = implode(',', $model->contract_id);
            if($model->save()){
                return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
            }
        }

        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

**Модель Company**

```
public function getContractList()
    {
        $contractList = Contract::find()->select('id, name')->all();
        $list = ArrayHelper::map( $contractList, 'id', 'name');
        return $list;
    }
```

**Форма create**

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'address')->textInput(['id' => 'address4','maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'info')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'contract_id[]')->dropDownList($model->ContractList, ['multiple' => 'multiple'] ); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <a href="/admin/contract" class="btn btn-outline-warning" style="margin-top: 28px; display: inline-block">Редактировать договора</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Сохранить', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

**Суть проблемы:**
Не знаю как теперь преобразовать строку с id'шниками из поля contract_id в договора и вывести их в GridView

Comment: *в поле contract_id(varchar) в таблице company хранятся id'шники 13,28,43....* Вот прямо так, в CSV??? меняйте срочно.

Comment: Akina, Да я бы с радостью. но это единственный пока что способ до которого додумался, понимаю что делаю не верно

Comment: Ну тогда FIND_IN_SET()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо же наоборот в таблицу `contract` добавить поле `company_id` и туда прописывать `id` компании. Таким образом контракт будет привязан к компании. Далее уже стандартными реляциями работать с контрактами компании.

```
class Company extends ActiveRecord
{
    public function getContracts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Contract::class, ['company_id' => 'id']);
    }
}

class Contract extends ActiveRecord
{
    public function getCompany()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Company::class, ['id' => 'company_id']);
    }
}
```

И се. Каждый контракт может получить данные компании, а каждая компания может получить данные всех контрактов.

Читать отсюда и дальше вниз. Там про связывание, получение данных, сохранение через метод `link()` и все прочее. https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/db-active-record#relational-data

Comment: Это сделано, а как вывести их в detailView?   вот var_dump                                  array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(47) "Аварийное-круглосуточное"
  [1]=>
  string(90) "Аварийный (с 17:00 до 8:00, выходные и праздничные дни)"
}

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос надо оформлять. Потому что без кода ничего непонятно.